# Removing trailing spaces with clang-format

Tags: clang-format

As the title says, I'm trying to get clang-format to remove the trailing white spaces of my files, but I fail to find the relevant option name.

Could anyone point me to the obvious?

Comment: I was under assumption it does this by default and the feature can not be even disabled. Could you have problem with the editor or some other plugin modifying the code after save?

Comment: Nope, because clang-format is run from the git pre-commit hook.

Comment: @MartinQuinson Could you figure this out?

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang-format does remove trailing whitespaces automatically.
You can test this by e.g. `clang-format -style=Google file.cpp -i`.

It is also useful to know most modern editors do have built-in options to do this and even more for you on save. Here are a few:

- In Sublime text settings set `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save` to true.
- In VScode set `files.trimTrailingWhitespace` to true.
- In Vim you need a vimrc file as described [here](https://howchoo.com/g/odg0mdyzmwr/vim-how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-on-save).
- etc.

Comment: Alas, the tue.nl link requires a login :(

Comment: It seems like it, it used to be accessible. I'll remove the link.

Comment: The Clang-Format guide does not list an option for removing trailing spaces: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html ... is there a different version?

Comment: It seems that they have removed it from the documentation. However clang-format still removes trailing whitespaces.

Comment: It seems clang-format only removes whitespace *if and only if* it formats the file in other ways.  There seems to be no way to use clang-format to merely/only trim whitespace without changing any other formatting in existing files.  Using `--style=none` changes nothing - including trailing whitespace.  (Using the IDE works on a file-by-file basis, but not a bulk basis.)